# Mapping Mac OS X's Mission Control Key to Ubuntu's Workspaces, with Synergy

Tags: mac, synergy

How can I map my `Mission Control` key ( which is alternatively <kbd>F4</kbd> if <kbd>fn</kbd> is pressed ) to be my command under Ubuntu to show all active workspaces?

When I press that key under Ubuntu, in the `Keyboard -> Custom Shortcuts` option under `Settings`, nothing happens. It's as if the key being pressed doesn't register.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/90223/synergy-key-mapping ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Unity, then install Unity Tweak Tool.

Then choose "window Spread." Under "Window Spread Shortcuts," click on "Disabled" next to "Start windows spread for all windows," and press the desired key (Mission Control key in your case).

That should do it.